# Giving margins/gaps in between column Flex components

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, flexbox

I am trying to give some margins between the buttons (Reset Filter/Apply Filter/Save & Apply Filter)in UI, I have used flex to align the buttons, but I am not able to give some margins/gaps between the buttons.
Any idea how to do it

Code :

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column justify-space-around">
    <v-btn
        text
        style="margin-left: 30px"
        color="primary"
        @click="resetFilter()">
        Reset Filter
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn
        v-if="!updatingSavedFilter"
        color="primary"
        @click="
        applyFilter()
        filterDropdownOpen = false">
        Apply Filter
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn
        color="primary"
        @click="
        validateAndSaveFilter()    
        filterDropdownOpen = "false">
        Save &amp; Apply Filter
    </v-btn>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're using Vuetify, am I right? In that case, you could add a margin class to each button:

```
<v-btn
   text
   style="margin-left: 30px"
   color="primary"
   class="mb-2"
   @click="resetFilter"
>
   Reset Filter
</v-btn>
```

See Vuetify's [spacing](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/spacing/) documentation.

On another subject: try to avoid inline style. Better add a class. In this case you can have something like

```
class="mb-2 ml-7"
```

That will give you 8px margin on the bottom and 28px margin on the left.

Also, when passing function name to @click, don't execute it, only pass the name (see my example above).

Comment: mb-2 did the trick for me for the vuetify buttons..Thnx a lot

Comment: Did not understand the last line about @click

Comment: @sromit When you're passing a method to @click directive, pass it only by its name as a reference, without parentheses, i.t. `@click="methodName"`. If you're passing it with parenthesis, you're actually executing this method immediately. The only time you pass a method with parentheses is when you need to pass some parameter to the method, i.e. `@click="myMethod(param)"`

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a height to be able to use `justify-content: space-around`. Like in this example:

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 300px;
}

.box button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <button>Button</button>
  <button>Button</button>
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

Or you can use the new `gap` property.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  gap: 20px;
}

.box button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <button>Button</button>
  <button>Button</button>
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

Or just set a `margin-top`

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.box button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}

.box button:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <button>Button</button>
  <button>Button</button>
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a universal css solution to set **gap** between flex items using the following CSS, instead of adding styles/classes to each child element:

```
.d-flex{
  gap: 10px;
  gap: 10px 20px; /* row-gap column gap */
  row-gap: 10px; /* sets only for rows */
  column-gap: 20px; /* sets only for columns */
}
```

Reference:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flexbox-background